# IIS + ASP.NET : where can I see logs for the server itself? Specifically throttling events

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging

I spent 2 days on figuring out why my service was stopping responding. Issue ended up being throttling. But none of the logs I dug through mentioned it.

What IIS/ASP.NET log can I look at to figure that out?

Here are the places I have checked:

1. IIS requests log (%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles)
2. "Microsoft/Windows/Application Server-Applications" system logs: Debug, Analytic
3. "Application" and "System" system logs
4. System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging and System.ServiceModel log sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Windows Server AppFabric it should tell you on the dashboard

[image]

Comment: accepted, since it answers the question. What about logs? Is there a comprehensive IIS execution log available?

Comment: I don't think you will find anything in an IIS log because as far as IIS is concerned a handler is called. You should be able to find more information using WCF and/or WF4 tracing. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513993.aspx

Comment: The AppFabric Dashboard uses the ETWTrackingProvider to extract info about instances. So I am guessing it gets this counter the same way. Not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

check this post if it helps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/01/09/net-hang-my-application-hangs-after-i-called-my-wcf-service-a-couple-of-times.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IIS and WAS logs are sent to System event log, use following filter query to get IIS/WAS relevant events:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-APPHOSTSVC"']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-FTP']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IisMetabaseAudit']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IISReset']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WMSVC"']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WAS']]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WAS-ListenerAdapter']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```