# Is there a Maximum number of workflow instances and what happens if i hit it?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Basic details: Workflow version 4, IIS hosted, App Fabric installed with persistence and tracking set up.

lets take this example. I have a list of X machines to do work against. in the initial workflow i do some validation on the list it self, then, in a foreach activity against the list, fire up a different workflow to do some actual work in the machines. This new workflow can take anywhere from 10 minutes to 2 weeks to complete depending on many factors.

My question is, what happens when the initial list is 200 or 2000 machines and i am spinning up that many instances of workflows on a server? Is there a maximum that will be allowed to run? If so, what happens in the original workflow that is looping through the list when it hits this maximum? Is this the way i should be handling a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow services are throttled by the same settings as WCF. That means that additional workflows exceeding the limits will be scheduled but will remain in the queue until they can be started.

See the links below for more info:

- [Throttling workflow services in WF4](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/11/17/throttling-workflow-services-in-wf4.aspx)
- [Question: Workflow Service
  stops responding after 464 messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272946/19676)